# Change the visible footer in Apache directory pages

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver

When I visit a directory listing page on my Apache server, this footer is visible:

```
Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80
```

How is it possible to modify parts of this footer to my liking?

Comment: Related, also see the [Sever Side Include (SSI)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/ssi.html) to include a footer in each page to avoid the repetition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`ReadmeName` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html) to mod_autoindex in the server configuration file (or in `.htaccess` if that is allowed). Example:

```
<!-- This would be located at http://localhost/FOOTER.html -->
<p>This is a test footer.</p>

# This would be in the config file or .htaccess file
ReadmeName /FOOTER.html
```

Another option: omit the leading forward slash to have httpd instead look for a FOOTER.html file in the listed directory, which you might want to hide in the listing:

```
ReadmeName FOOTER.html
IndexIgnore FOOTER.html
```

If no FOOTER.html file exists in a directory, the default footer giving the server version will be displayed.

Comment: If the direcives (ReadmeName and IndexIgnore) are added into the .htaccess file, only current folder is affected. The subfolder (which does not have the same .htaccess ) will have default footer again. So it would be better to add these directives into apache server configuration section .

Answer (score 0):

To remove server signature you need to add apache2 config options:

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
```

To add header and footer made by you, you need to (as june matsu answered):

1. enable rewrite
2. add `AllowOverride All` in right place in apache2 configuration
3. add the below text in `.htaccess` file in folder which you are listing:

```
HeaderName /header.html
ReadmeName /footer.html
IndexIgnore header.html footer.html .htaccess
```

4. add files in web root: `header.html` and `footer.html`
5. restart apache2

Answer (score -1):

you can try this step

Open a terminal and typing the command

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite [enter]
 Enabling rewrite module. ( the message indicates that a2enmod is active)
```

Then open the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default with your favorite editor, for example:

```
 sudo pluma /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

change "AllowOverride none" to "AllowOverride All" (without the quotes), then save and exit.
     The next step to restart apache2

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: `mod_rewrite` rewrites the URL requested by the browser, not the content of the returned page (such as an autoindex).