# Apache2 doesn't seem to load conf.d/ files

Tags: apache-http-server

I have a web server, running using `Apache/2.2.22` on `Debian/7.8`.

I would like to disable the signature that is added at the end of error pages:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /sdffds.html was not found on this server.
_____________________________
Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at xxx Port 80  <-- this
```

I should be able to do this by editing the `/etc/apache2/conf.d/security` file. I did so by uncommenting `ServerSignature Off` (and commenting `ServerSignature On`). However, after reloading/restarting apache2, this doesn't work.

I checked `apache2.conf`, the instruction `Include conf.d/` is here. This means either apache2 is not looking at `conf.d` files properly, or I have made a mistake editing `conf.d/security`.

To be sure, I edited `apache2.conf` and put `Include conf.d/security`, it works.

Why is apache2 not properly looking to `conf.d/` files?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/438565/change-the-visible-footer-in-apache-directory-pages

Comment: The question is why apache2 is not looking to conf.d/ files. This is not the behaviour I am expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure Apache will only pick up files that end in ".conf" from the conf.d directory.

Try changing ..conf.d/security to ..conf.d/security.conf

Alternatively you can add "ServerSignature Off" to the primary configuration file and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `Include conf.d/` is loading all files (in alphabetical order i think) irrespective of extension from `conf.d/` . I was also facing the same issue after setting `ServerSignature Off` in `security` file and the reason was I have backup of original security file inside `conf.d/` called `security.bak` (which contains `ServerSignature On`). So you have to make sure that there is no other file present in `conf.d/` which can cause conflict. Because in my case, `security.bak` was loading after `security` that's why it was overriding my settings. 
Solution provided by Jacob Margason will solve your issue too because adding `ServerSignature Off` at the end of `apache2.conf` overrides everything